# make function available without import globally

Tags: python, import, global-variables

let's say I wanted to make a core library for a project, with functions like:

```
def foo(x):
    """common, useful function"""
```

and I want to make these functions globally available in my project so that when I call them in a file, I don't need to import them.  I have a virtualenv, so I feel like I should be able to modify my interpreter to make them globally available, but wasn't sure if there was any established methodologies behind this.  I am aware it defies some pythonic principles.

Comment: You could create your own launcher script that prepares some global variables and executes the other script in that context.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you don't want to import them?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to import them.

Comment: @Prune But a module has to be imported.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for default imports. I don't think Python does that, except for the built-in standard functions.

Comment: it would be useful as a DSL that extends python.  Basically it was just a thought for something interesting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a custom "launcher" that sets up some global variables and executes the code in a python file:

```
from sys import argv

# we read the code of the file passed as the first CLI argument
with open(argv[1]) as fin:
    code = fin.read()

# just an example: this will be available in the executed python file
def my_function():
    return "World"


global_variables = {
    'MY_CONSTANT': "Hello",  # prepare a global variable
    'my_function': my_function  # prepare a global function
}

exec(code, global_variables)  # run the file with new global variables
```

Use it like this: `python launcher.py my_dsl_file.py`.

Example `my_dsl_file.py`:

```
# notice: no imports at all
print(MY_CONSTANT)
print(my_function())
```

Interestingly Python (at least CPython) uses a different way to setup some useful functions like `help`. It runs a file called `site.py` that adds some values to the `builtins` module.

```
import builtins


def my_function():
    return "World"

builtins.MY_CONSTANT = "Hello"
builtins.my_function = my_function


# run your file like above or simply import it
import <your file>
```

I wouldn't recommend either of these ways. A simple `from <your library> import *` is a much better approach.

The downside of the first two variants is that no tool will know anything about your injected globals. E.g. `mypy`, `flake8` and all IDEs i know of will fail.